# check whether a convolution has compact support

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, convolution

I am working on a problem which lead me to the following integral, given $h:R \rightarrow R$ is a smooth nonzero  function with compact support. For $\epsilon>0$, let$${u_\epsilon(x)} ＝{ \frac{ \intop\nolimits_{-\infty }^{\infty }(x-y)  e^{-K(x,y)/\epsilon}dy  }{ \intop\nolimits_{-\infty }^{\infty } e^{-K(x,y)/\epsilon}dy }}, \forall x \in R,$$where $K(x,y)=\frac{1}{4}(x-y)^2+\frac{1}{2}h(y) $ for $x,y\in R$.
Is each ${u_\epsilon(x)} $ a smooth function with compact support? Must $ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+} {u_\epsilon(x)}$ exist? If it exist what is the value?

Comment: What did you try :)  where are you stuck ?

Comment: In fact , I am new to distribution theory. pls give some hint. Is there any lemma useful in this prob?

Comment: Yes : the convolution. Let $g(x) = x e^{-x^2/4}$ and $f(x) = e^{h(x)/2}$ what can you say of $g \ast h(x)$ ?

Comment: that is numerator. How to proceed? What property can I use?

Comment: Do you realize $f$ is non negative and has a compact support, while $g(x)$ is non-negative or non-positive for $x$ large enough ?

Comment: $g(x)\rightarrow 0$  as x goes to +- infinity right?

Comment: So what ? Say $support(f) \subset [-A,A]$, note that $g(x) > 0$ for $x > 0$. What do you get for $f \ast g(x)$ when $x > A$ ? And for $|f \ast g(x)|$ ?

Comment: $f \ast g(x)>0$ when $x > A$

Comment: Yes, and for its decay, since $g(x)$ is decreasing for say $x > M$ then  $\|f\|_{L^1}g(x-A) > f \ast g(x) > \|f\|_{L^1}g(x+A)$

Comment: How can $\|f\|_{L^1}g(x-A) > f \ast g(x) > \|f\|_{L^1}g(x+A)$ lead to ${u_\epsilon(x)}$ has compact support. I can only see $f \ast g(x)>0$ tends to 0 as x goes infinity.

Comment: What I wrote shows It won't have a compact support (if $f$ is non-negative i.e. $h$ is real)

Comment: Thank you very much. I will write a complete solution for this problem after gain some familiarity on this subject. Let $m(x) =  e^{-x^2/4}$ How about estimating $ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+} {u_\epsilon(x)}$=$ \lim_{\epsilon\to 0+}\frac{f \ast g(x)}{m \ast g(x)}$

Comment: maybe $g(x) = x e^{-x^2/4\epsilon}$$f(x) = e^{h(x)/2\epsilon}$