# compact support intuition needed

Tags: intuition, distribution-theory

I am studying Distribution theory. But I am curious about that why we coin compact support.  In what situation is it useful? Can any one give an intuitive way to explain this concept?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why do we require that $\varphi(x) = 0$ for $x$ large enough  ? Because it allows us to **integrate by parts without fear** : 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty T(x) \varphi'(x)dx = \lim_{x \to \infty} T(x)\varphi(x)-T(-x)\varphi(-x)-\int_{-\infty}^\infty T'(x) \varphi(x)dx$$
Here $\varphi \in C^\infty_c$ and $T$ is a distribution, so $T(x)\varphi(x)$ doesn't make sense, but if you assume that $\varphi(x) = 0$ for $|x| > M$ then clearly $\lim_{x \to \infty} T(x)\varphi(x)-T(-x)\varphi(-x) = 0$ and it makes sense to write
$$\langle T,\varphi' \rangle =\int_{-\infty}^\infty T(x) \varphi'(x)dx = -\int_{-\infty}^\infty T'(x) \varphi(x)dx=-\langle T',\varphi \rangle \tag{1}$$
which is exactly what we need for defining $\delta'$ the derivative of the Dirac delta and the derivatives of distributions in general.

Now the big question : how do you prove that $(1)$ makes sense (that it doesn't lead to some contradictions) ? Well you can take it as a definition, so nothing to prove,

or you can show that when defining the distributions as linear operators $C^\infty_c \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous for the test function space topology,  then the differentiation operator $\langle T,.\rangle \mapsto \langle T',.\rangle$ is continuous in the sense of distributions.

---

See also the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), where we replace the compact support property by a decay $o(x^{-k})$ at $\infty$, discarding the distributions with a too large grow rate and keeping the so-called tempered distributions.

Comment: Thank you for your ans. If you have time ,pls take a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035637/check-whether-a-convolution-has-compact-support.It is quite hard for me.

Answer (score 3):

The functions with compact support are those that are zero outside of a compact set. This is quite useful in distributions as it tells us that the function dosent grow indefinitely. It is useful also in the theory of Differential Equations, Functional Analysis, Toplogy. Some examples include [Bump Function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BumpFunction.html). Also refer [Support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) for different types of support.

Comment: Functions of compact support also have a very large dual space. Operations easily defined on the functions of compact support (like fourier transform) can be extended to this dual space and gain meaning on a much wider class of functions.

Comment: How to defined a function's dual space. How can we compare those dual spaces?

Comment: @aswe2277 before the distributions, you need to look at the Banach and Hilbert spaces ($C^k([a,b]), L^1,L^2,L^p,l^2, L^2([0,1])$), you need to formalize the Fourier series and the Fourier transform under this "functional analysis" framework, and get an intuition for the concept of continuity / boundedness, operator norm, semi-norm, topology, dual space...

Comment: Could you recommend some clear book or  pdf note?

Comment: @aswe2277  The keyword are what I wrote : functional analysis, Lp space, dual space, operator norm, ...

Comment: Reed and Simon volume 1 (Methods in Mathematical Physics?) is good on dual spaces which might be in your college library.